# How to create a views filter for users who have never accessed a site?

Tags: 7, users, views

I have a view where I am trying to show all users who have a last access value of `never`, meaning they have never logged in.

The filter however expects a Date value which is no help to me because I just need to filter by users who have never accessed.

[image]

Does anyone know a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using following simple steps:

1. Add filter criteria **User: Last access** or **User: Last login** is equal to **1970-01-01**

[image]

2. You could see the **users.access = 0** in query

[image]

> Note: Drupal uses Unix time. The unix time stamp is a way to track
>   time as a running total of seconds. This count starts at the Unix
>   Epoch on January 1st, 1970 at UTC. Therefore, the unix time stamp is
>   merely the number of seconds between a particular date and the Unix
>   Epoch.

Comment: +1 Good answer. Slight wrinkle though: As my site time zone is set at GMT+2 I had to set my access to 1970-01-01 02:00:00. Don't know what will happen if users are allowed to set their own time zone. Probably nothing.

Comment: Okay so this works better: Last access Is less than or equal to, Value 1970-01-02

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_views_query_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.api.php/function/hook_views_query_alter/7.x-3.x)

> Alter the query before executing the query.

Add a filter to your view on `User: Last access` and set `Is equal to` with `Value: today`

Next create a module and add following:

```
function MODULE_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if ($view->name == 'useraccess') { // add your view name instead
    foreach ($query->where as &$condition_group) {
      foreach ($condition_group['conditions'] as &$condition) {
        if (strpos($condition['field'], 'users.access') === 0) {
          $condition = array(
              'field' => 'users.access',
              'value' => array(null),
              'operator' => '=',
          );
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use GMT+x you can use "**Regular expression**" instead of "is equal to" and use **^0$** as expression.

The SQL result will be:

```
...
WHERE (( (users.uid NOT IN  ('0')) AND (users.access RLIKE '^0$') ))
...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the value field just enter "never", exactly as it shows on /admin/people